# Printing single element of object in array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, system.out

Trying to store objects in an array and to later print them out. Keep getting the actual location in memory instead. Can't remember for the life of me how to print the contents and not the locations.

```
case VIEW_RECIPE:
            System.out.println("Please enter the recipe ID:");
            searchIndex = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(recipeArray[searchIndex-1]);
            break;
case CREATE_RECIPE:
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
            recipeArray[recipe.getRecipeId() -1] = recipe; //-1 to store in element 0;
            break;
```

So assuming there is a recipe at index 0 of the recipeArray[], how do I print it. this code only gives me the memory location, and looping through is impractical.

tried the code

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(recipeArray[searchIndex-1]));
```

but it says the toString should be deepToString, or the array should be long.

EDIT: After being asked for the recipe class here it is

```
package potluck;
import java.util.*;


public class Recipe {

private int recipeId = 0;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private String attribution; 
private String dateAdded;
private String category;
private String listOfIngredients; 
private String tags;
private String steps;  
private String comments; 


public Recipe(){ //constructor
    recipeId += 1;
    setAttribution(); 
    setDateAdded();
    setCategory();
    setListOfIngredients(); 
    setTags();
    setSteps();
    System.out.println("Thank you for the recipe, it's Id is "+recipeId);
    System.out.println("Use this to find it later.");
    System.out.println();
}
```

everything else is getters and setters

Comment: Can you share the Recipe class? I'd like to see what kind of data you're using for it.

Comment: Does `Recipe` override `toString()`?

Comment: You're already printing the contents. It's just that the default `toString()` method (inherited from `java.lang.Object`) prints the memory location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `toString()` methond in Recipe class. For example:

```
class Recipe {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public String toString() {
        return "Recipe#" + id + ": " + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so I override the toString, then how do I use it? Like i'm trying to print everything in the recipe, Name, Date added, there's a bunch of fields that are user entered.

Comment: That's for you to decide what information you'd like to be exposed in toString(). You can use all of your class fields or some of them or none (although the later whould be strange).

Comment: @SamMurdock The usual method is to create getters for each variable you wish to obtain, otherwise you can return them all in one long return statement.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are wrote a class for recipes. If so, override its `toString()` method and return what you want. This will be print when you use `System.out.println()`. `println(Object o)` method simply calls the `toString()` method of the given object and write the returned `String` to the console.